# GWT Stackpanel handler for open event

Tags: events, gwt, handler, stackpanel

is there any way to get an event when I switch between widget on a Stackpanel?
something like an openhandler for stackpanel. I have to know the index of
an open Widget on a Stackpanel.

Comment: well your question isn't so clear to me... can you post an example?

Comment: Well, I have got a Stackpanel with some Widget on it. One Widget is open. Now I want to have a handler that notice me when the user is open another widget. So that I always know which Child of the Stackpanel is open.. Know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using StackLayoutPanel: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/StackLayoutPanel.html

Use the `addSelectionHandler()` method. To get the selected widget, you can use `getVisibleIndex()` or `getVisibleWidget()`.

```
myStackPanel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {

        int selectedWidgetIndex = stackPanel.getVisibleIndex());

        //Do stuff with the selectedWidgetIndex
    }
});
```

EDIT: This is using StackLayoutPanel, the OP uses StackPanel. The difference between them is that StackPanel is for quirks mode and StackLayout Panel for Standards Mode. I would StackLayoutPanel or any Layout related widget as new GWT widgets uses them, like the new DataGrid.

Comment: Thank yout, but:
- The method addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>(){}) is undefined for the type StackPanel
- The method getVisibleIndex() is undefined for the type StackPanel

I think a StackPanel hasn't methods like this?!

Comment: You are right, I was checking StackLayoutPanel. You can replace your StackPanel if you don't have any compatibility issues.

Comment: Which GWT version are you using? In GWT 2.4 StackPanel has `getSelectedIndex()`.

Comment: I use 2.4, but that doesn't help me. Because that method notice me if something is already happenend. What I need is a Handler that notice me when something is changed at the stackpanel.
I will try StacklayoutPanel then..

Answer (score 1):

You can add a click handler on a DecoratedStackPanel (and possibly a StackPanel) and use getSelectedIndex() as below:

```
myDecoratedStackPanel.addHandler(new ClickHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent)
    {
        Window.alert("" + myDecoratedStackPanel.getSelectedIndex());
    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

By overridding the `showStack` method, it is a breeze. Try something like:

```
public class StackPanelX extends StackPanel implements IHasChangeHandler {

    String ctx_id=null;
    IChangeHandler chandler=null;

    public StackPanelX() {
        super();
    }

    public void showStack(int index) {
        int currentStack = this.getSelectedIndex(); 

        super.showStack(index);

        if (currentStack!=index)
            if (chandler!=null) 
                chandler.onChange(ctx_id, new Variant(index));

    }

    @Override
    public void setChangeHandler(String ctx_id, IChangeHandler handler) {
        this.ctx_id=ctx_id;
        this.chandler=handler;
    }

}
```